# GPIO for Raspberry PI GPIO Group

Tags: permissions, python, devices

I grabbed the image for Ubuntu on Raspberry PI over here https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi loaded a L928N python program via a virtualenv as the ubuntu user and got an error. Did some digging and some testing turned out to be ubuntu group could not access `/dev/gpiomem` which belongs to `root root`

So the option I was left with was to run my python program as root but virtualenv was not really isolating my programs then. It appeared `sudo` was pulling everything from root's global python setup. Seeing as I run a couple project on the raspberry pi having them overlap can cause me nights of frustration trying to understand why something broke (when a dep updates for one project and not another).

So I made `/dev/gpiomem` group `gpio` which ubuntu user is apart of. Viola python, pip, virtualenv and my project worked without `sudo` in a controlled isolated virtualenv!

Now a couple days later login run the program and it fails. Turns out `/dev/gpiomem` reverted back to `root root`.

Questions I have are A) is there a better way to give ubuntu access to `/dev/gpiomem` B) is there a way to ensure that the group stays the same (assuming A is no).

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, instead of the gpio group, add your user to the `dialout` group to give yourself access to the GPIO pins.

(This is documented in the `/usr/share/doc/rpi.gpio-common/README.Debian` file that is installed by the `rpi.gpio-common` package.)

As 4xy pointed out, installing the `rpi.gpio-common` package will set up the udev rules.

I had to reboot my Pi after installing `rpi.gpio-common` and adding my user to the `dialout` group, and then I was able to access the GPIO pins as a normal user.

---

Putting it all together:

```
sudo apt install rpi.gpio-common
sudo adduser "${USER}" dialout
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just ran into this. I added the group gpio and added root and my user to that group.
I then copied the udev rule 99-com.rules from a raspbian image. Reboot and all works. I've pasted the rules file here for completeness. This is how the foundation do it so must be right. ;)

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", GROUP="input", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="i2c-dev", GROUP="i2c", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="spidev", GROUP="spi", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"

SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio*", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys/class/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/gpio;\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys/devices/virtual/gpio && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/virtual/gpio;\
        chown -R root:gpio /sys$devpath && chmod -R 770 /sys$devpath\
'"

KERNEL=="ttyAMA[01]", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
        ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; \
        if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial0; then \
                echo 0;\
        elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart0 $ALIASES/serial1; then \
                echo 1; \
        else \
                exit 1; \
        fi\
'", SYMLINK+="serial%c"

KERNEL=="ttyS0", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c '\
        ALIASES=/proc/device-tree/aliases; \
        if cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial0; then \
                echo 0; \
        elif cmp -s $ALIASES/uart1 $ALIASES/serial1; then \
                echo 1; \
        else \
                exit 1; \
        fi \
```

Comment: I stumbled onto these `.rules` files but then some other work came up. Thanks for the starting template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard. `ubuntu` user should be also added to `i2c, spi, input` and `gpio` groups.

Answer (score 1):

No need to manually add these rules.

```
sudo apt install rpi.gpio-common
```